# Вход на сайт только по логину

Tags: yii

Здравствуйте! Я новичок в Yii. Где мне лучше прописать условие, что если гость, то отправить его на страницу для входа (форму) Заранее спасибо! Не ругать, пож-та

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Yii у объекта пользователя (Yii::app()->user) есть свойство returnUrl, которое определяет, куда будет посылаться незалогиненный пользователь при доступе к запрещенным ресурсам. Для того, чтобы "забанить" какой-либо экшен в контроллере, можно воспользоваться фильтром accessControl - при попытке доступа такого заблокированного экшена пользователя автоматом перешлет на страницу входа, указанную в returnUrl. Пример использования можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/topics.auth#sec-5).

Answer (score 0):

Обычно все контроллеры наследуются от класса `Controller`.

Файл, содержащий данный класс, находится в `/protected/components/Controller.php`

В этом классе есть метод `init()`, в нем и делайте проверку, залогинен пользователь или нет